# How to import acquisition date from Google Analytics to Google Sheet on daily basis

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I have been using the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) for a while now to export data from GA and to run calculation on it via spreadsheet.

one of the things that I'm not able to do is to create a cohort analysis based on acquisition date or first session date.

Is there any way to have acquisition date or first session date as a dimension while using the Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such option with tools you are using (GA + GA Sheets Add-On). You better try to use BigQuery for this purpose.